# Which extension version to choose? 32-bit? 64-bit? It's depends on my system(32-bit/64-bit) or Python(32-bit/64-bit)?

Tags: python

As titled, I want to download pyHook from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyhook

For pyHook there are several versions such as:

```
pyHook‑1.5.1‑cp27‑cp27m‑win32.whl
pyHook‑1.5.1‑cp27‑cp27m‑win_amd64.whl
pyHook‑1.5.1‑cp34‑cp34m‑win32.whl
pyHook‑1.5.1‑cp34‑cp34m‑win_amd64.whl
pyHook‑1.5.1‑cp35‑cp35m‑win32.whl
pyHook‑1.5.1‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl
pyHook‑1.5.1‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl
pyHook‑1.5.1‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl
```

The version of the extension carries the meaning of the Python version(32-bit/64bit) has to be same as it or my Windows version?

I am currently using Windows 10 and I wasted 2 day to do research about this. Looking for someone to enlight me as I am really a beginner to Python.

Thank you!!

Comment: The same as your python-build.

Comment: You can run 32 bit applications on 64 bit system, you can't do it other way round (well, there are some hacks enabling it but these are hacks), but it's preferred to use 64 bits.

Comment: You have to choose the version of pyHook that matches exactly with the version of python you have. So, if you have python 2, then you have to have one of the `cp27` versions. Similarly with python 3 you have to match the exact version of python (3.4, 3.5, 3.6), Plus you have to match the 32/64 bit version of **python**.

Comment: If you want a concrete answer for you specific case, you'll have to tell us your Python version: `python -V`.

Comment: Alright, I'm using Windows 10(64bit) and Python I'm actually quite flexible as long as the extension works. I am trying to install different version of python right now..

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for your quick reply. I get my problem solved!! The extension follows the Python version(32bit/64bit) cause I couldn't install 32-bit extension on 64-bit Python and only can install 32-bit extension on 32-bit Python. 

Actually I successfully installed both but the keylogger python file doesn't record character well so I thought is extension version wrong.

After that I just found out the keylogger python code doesn't have any problem but the first line lacking of "# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-" and cause the logging of key became some unreadable character.